# Container can't ping github.com but host can

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I have the following setup:

`[ LXC Container running Debian ] <--> virbr0 <--> [Fedora 24 host]`

DNS resolve works for every single domain I've tried to so far from the host and from the container. Except "github.com" and any of it's IP addresses (I get a `Destination Host Unreachable` error).

Again...only for github.com (but also pinging the IP directly). The container has the following `/etc/resolv.conf`:

`nameserver 192.168.122.1`

Which is the host. Which is able to both resolve and ping github.com. So does *anyone* have an idea what might be going on here? Because this is causing the software installed in the container (nextcloud) to not work properly anymore. (Also, this behaviour happens from all my LXC containers).

Comment: Does the host run a nameserver?

Comment: No, there is a central nameserver on the network. So the host only has "nameserver 10.7.1.2" in it's resolv.conf.

Comment: so it seems you have to change the IP in the container (if your host has proper network "routing" settings)
Or setup a forwarder on the host

Comment: @DennisNolte Well it's not just a nameserver problem. It's that I can't reach certain IP's. I've just done a bit of testing and from ~20 domains, I can only not reach "github" and "gitlab". But again, the same thing happens when I pin them by IP (e.g. 104.210.2.228). So it can't just be a nameserver issue :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this problem, can you post the /etc/network/interfaces file for the container?

If you have a netmask of 255.0.0.0 that could be a problem, because github.com's IP is 192.30.253.113. Switching the netmask to 255.255.255.0 may resolve this after restarting the container.

I just had a similar problem on a debian VirtualBox machine and this resolved it for me.

Comment: I have this issue reproduced.
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.49.168.208  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.49.168.255
        inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe17:bc58  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> .

From host ping github.com
PING github.com (20.205.243.166) 56(84) bytes of data.

But from lxc container cannot ping.